# ParseQuery - How can I do a "Where In" like query using Parse?

Tags: parse-platform, where-clause, where-in

I'm new to Parse and I am trying to get all the Parse users with mobile numbers that matches any of the mobile numbers stored in my generic list, is there an easy way to do this?

I created a custom field called "mobile" under the User class in Parse, then I also have a list of mobile numbers where I want to check if they were already used and registered in my User class.

In SQL I might do something like:

SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE mobile IN ("+01123123", "+01455123", "+0141234", "+123123123", "+42331321" )

I really don't know how to do this in Parse, I'm very sorry if this question has been asked before but I've been stuck for some time now with no luck googling and searching.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Which SDK are you using?

Comment: See rest API docs 'queries'section "$whereIn"

Comment: Hi Ricky and Robert, thanks for the comments!  I am using a Xamarin SDK for Android.  I was able to solve the issue using the "Contains" Linq query, I'm not sure how to paste the codes properly here but the working Parse query looks like this:  var query = 
    from userTable in ParseUser.Query
     where contactNumbers.Contains( userTable.Get<string>("mobile") )
    select userTable;

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies!  I was able to solve this issue using LINQ "Contains" from https://www.parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#queries

Here is my working query

```
ArrayList contactNumbers = new ArrayList();

contactNumbers.Add("0123456712");
contactNumbers.Add("0555555555");
contactNumbers.Add("0412828282");

var query = 
from userTable in ParseUser.Query
where contactNumbers.Contains( userTable.Get<string>("mobile") )
select userTable;
```